# scipy.integrate.quad() without using lambda

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, numerical-integration

I am currently making a program that involves rectification. The only module that can do complex integration is Scipy with its `scipy.integrate.quad()` command. However, in my code, I need to have a variable that represents the function itself, since there will eventually be more different functions used in the rectification process that are derived by using the preceding equation. Every source that I have seen about the command either involves lambda or creating a definition that outputs an equation.**You** input the equation manually. So, my question is, is there any way to integrate it without doing that? Here's my code:

```
import scipy                                                   
import sympy
from scipy.integrate import quad

def rectify(smallestterm, nextsmallestterm, poly, coef, exp):
   test = rectification(coef,exp)
   a = quad(test, smallestterm, nextsmallestterm)
   print(a)
   a = a[0]
   dist = a/2
   return dist     
def test(x):
   return rectification(coef, exp)
def rectification(coef, exp):
   u = Poly(lint(coef,exp)) #Generated Equation
   b = u.all_coeffs()
   poly = b
   c = len(poly) - 1
   exponents = []
   while c + 1 > 0:
       exponents.append(c)
       c = c - 1
   poly = function(poly,exponents)   #Generated Equation in a form that can actually be used and identified as a function.
   return sqrt(1+(pow(diff(poly),2)))
```

Where `coef` is a list of the leading coefficients of a polynomial and `exp` is a list of the leading exponents of a polynomial. Essentially, they will both be indirectly combined in another definition, `function(coef, exp)` (code for it not shown) that outputs the polynomial (the variable "`poly`").

i.e.

`function([2,4,5],[1,6,0])` Outputs

> 4*x**6 + 2*x + 5

**This code (above the function code) does not work as it doesn't allow me to use the variable "a" to represent an entire function, as it only recognizes "a" as a function in itself.** So, lambda does not work in my case. I can't simply do something like:

```
import scipy
import sympy
from scipy.integrate import quad
poly = 2*x**5 + 5*x**4 - 4*x**2 + 10   #Some complicated polynomial
d = diff(poly) #differential of polynomial
a = sqrt(1+(pow(d,2)))
e = quad(a, 1, 5)
e = e[1]/2
return e
```

If you need to see my full code to understand any other functions in this code, please do ask and I will happily provide it!

Comment: Actually, it would probably help to show _less_ code. Reduce your code sample to the [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed to demonstrate the issue; for example, you could use a simpler mathematical function and avoid bring in the `Poly` class (which you don't even define here), and you could also remove a bunch of `print` statements, and you could remove the unused `sympy` import. Also, despite all this explanation I still don't understand, why don't you want to use a lambda function? (Linking to the full code would still be useful.)

Comment: @DavidZ Will do! Here's the problem with using the lambda function: In my code, I want to give the program an input so it will make an equation out of it and then integrate the equation. This equation is by no means easy to achieve manually, so that is why I want to get the equation from the code (lint(coef,exp)). Since I will end up having multiple equations, I will set every new equation to some variable "a." The problem with lambda in this sense is that it just looks at "a" as simply the equation "y = a," not (let's say a = 2*x^2 + 6)  "y = 2*x^2 + 6". It ignores it as a storing variable.

Comment: Hmm... I still don't understand. Lambda functions are just functions, not equations. When you write `lambda x: 2*x**2+6` that represents a function that takes in `x` and returns the numerical value of `2*x**2+6`. It doesn't set that equal to anything (if by "equation" you mean a mathematical equation), and it doesn't assign it to anything (if by "equation" you mean a Python assignment), though of course you can assign the lambda function _itself_ to a variable (`a = lambda x: 2*x**2+6`). I don't see why you couldn't just put your expression into a lambda function and assign that to a variable.

Answer (score 4):

To my understanding, your code produces *symbolic expressions* using SymPy. These are not *functions* in the sense of Python, as they cannot be called. So they can't be used directly as the first argument of `quad`. SymPy provides [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) method that wraps the expression into a function:

```
quad(lambdify(x, expr), 0, 1)
```

Here `expr` can be any symbolic expression with variable `x` in it, for example `expr = 4*x**6 + 2*x + 5`.

Comment: You, my friend, are a Saint! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ohhh, _that's_ what this was about? In that case I would also refer you to the [sympy `lambdify` function](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify).

Comment: @BobbySanchez Please see the revised version, using lambdify as suggested by David Z.